# SSL connection via SOCKS5 proxy

Tags: c, openssl, socks

I am trying to write a C code to open an SSL connection with a remote server via a SOCKS5 proxy server.

I have successfully opened a tcp connection with the SOCKS5 proxy server. However, I do not know how to make an SSL connection with the remote server (different from proxy server).

```
// p->ai_addr has the SOCKS5 proxy address
m_sock_fd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
connect(m_sock_fd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen);

char socks5_request[256] = {0}, response[256] = {0};
sprintf(socks5_request, "\5\1\0");
send(m_sock_fd, socks5_request, 4, 0);
recv(m_sock_fd, response, 256, 0);

assert(response[0] == '\5' && response[1] == '\0'); // OK

m_ssl_ctx = SSL_CTX_new(SSLv23_client_method());
m_ssl = SSL_new(m_ssl_ctx);
SSL_set_fd(m_ssl, m_sock_fd);

SSL_connect(m_ssl); // returns -1
```

SSL_connect failed and gave error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:ssl/record/ssl3_record.c:332:

I have two questions.

1. Why am I getting this error?
2. where do I specify the remote IP address when making the SSL connection?

Update 4/2/2019

Code below is for sending connect request to proxy server. The last call for CheckConnectivity() found the connection closed.

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
memset(&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("*.*.*.*");
addr.sin_port = htons(443);

SOCKSRequest connect_request;

// 5: protocol number, 1: connect, 0: reserved, 1: ipv4
connect_request.m_version = '\5';
connect_request.m_type = '\1';
connect_request.m_reserved = '\0';
connect_request.m_addr_type = '\1';

connect_request.m_ip = addr.sin_addr.s_addr;
connect_request.m_port = addr.sin_port;

CheckConnectivitiy();

if (!send(m_sock_fd, &connect_request, 4, 0))
    return 0;

CheckConnectivitiy();

if (!send(m_sock_fd, &connect_request.m_ip, sizeof(in_addr), 0))
    return 0;

CheckConnectivitiy();

if (!send(m_sock_fd, &connect_request.m_port, 2, 0))
    return 0;

CheckConnectivitiy();  // connection was closed by peer here!
```

Implementation of CheckConnectivity.

```
int CheckConnectivitiy() const
{
    int error = 0;
    socklen_t len = sizeof (error);
    int retval = getsockopt (m_sock_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_ERROR, &error, &len);

    if (retval != 0) 
    {
        /* there was a problem getting the error code */
        fprintf(stderr, "error getting socket error code: %s\n", strerror(retval));
        return 0;
    }

    if (error != 0) 
    {
        /* socket has a non zero error status */
        fprintf(stderr, "socket error: %s\n", strerror(error));
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need only 1 connection, you to the proxy. You tell the proxy where it should connect to next (you are not doing that!). Only if the proxy successfully connects will you have a valid connection to the target server. Only then can you send the SSL/TLS handshake, as if you had connected to the target server directly.

I suggest you read [RFC 1928](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1928) for the SOCKS v5 protocol. You are sending an Authentication request and reading its response, but you are not sending a Connect request and reading is response, before you attempt to use SSL/TLS. That is why the handshake is failing. You are not connected to the target server yet.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation! I now, after authentication, send a connect request, and the reply looks OK (REPLY == x'00'). However, I got SIGPIPE when calling SSL_connect(m_ssl). It looks like the remote server has closed the connection. What would be the best way to investigate this?

Comment: Looks like the remote server closed the connection after I sent the connect request.

Comment: @chukunu not enough information to diagnose that. Is the proxy closing is connecting to you, or is the remote server closing is connection to the proxy? If the layer, does it do so as soon as the proxy connects, or after you begin sending the SSL/TLS handshake?

Comment: After adding code to check connectivity after every action, I found the connection was closed immediately after the connect request had been sent (please see the updated question). So the closing has nothing to do with SSL/TLS. Still not sure whether the proxy or the remote one closed the connection. What would be the best way to know it?

Comment: @chukunu you would need to run a packet sniffer on both sides of the proxy to see what is really happening. But HOW are you checking the connectivity? The only real way you can do that is to read from the socket, and you should not be doing that while in the middle of sending the bytes of a a command. Also, `send()` returns the number of bytes sent, or -1 on error, it will *never* return 0 when the buffer length is not 0. You need to change your `if (!send(...))` to handle errors properly.